# CALCULATE - how does AND logic work when multiple FILTERS are used?

Tags: powerbi, dax

When there are multiple filters, they're evaluated by using the AND logical operator. That means all conditions must be TRUE at the same time.

I understand this when the filters are like:
AMOUNT>100, CATEGORY='Sales'

However, when one or all of the filters are given by FILTER formula, I am unable to visualise how the AND logic works (and what does all conditions must be true mean because a condition [FILTER] itself is a table). Please can you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

All of the filters will be part of an [expanded table](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/expanded-tables-in-dax/) and ultimately each condition is a set of rules for specific columns on this expanded table.